# Effect of Reward Decay Factor in Reinforcement Learning

Tags: reinforcement-learning

The reinforcement learning penalizes reward at a long horizon by a factor of $\gamma^t$, where $\gamma$ is reward decay factor and $t$ is the time delay before collecting the reward. I do not understand why we need such a reward factor except for making the potentially infinite sum of rewards convergence:

1. In practice, usually there is no such analogy for such reward decay in environment setup. For example, we do not say winning a game with 10 minutes is "half as good as" winning a game with 5 minutes. Why do we need such a factor?
2. Is the value of the reward decay factor completely arbitrary? OpenAI dota agent  "we annealed γ from 0.998 (valuing future rewards with a half-life of 46 seconds) to 0.9997 (valuing future rewards with a half-life of five minutes)". How do we pick the value of reward decay?
3. Is there anyway to completely get rid of this hyperparameter?

Comment: After watching Berkeley CS285 video, one point I get for reward decay factor is it forces the algorithm to focus more on the short term rewards, thereby reducing the variance of value function.